# Problem getting Checkbox items on the ListView

Tags: java, android

I used before setListAdapter with simple_multiple_choice to make listview with checkboxes.

And then I did to get size and chosed positions:

```
SparseBooleanArray checked = list.getCheckedItemPositions();
cont = list.getCheckedItemPositions().size();

if (checked.get(i)) 
{
...
```

But now I needed more control on the layout, so i'm doing the listview on the xml, something like:

```
<listview>
<checkboxes id=.../>
</listview>
```

using setAdapter to those ids.

The listview is correctlyt populated (as before), **problem is**, now the SparseBooleanArray don't work. Thar variable 'cont', gives me 0, and 'checked' is null.

To make sure that 'list' is ok:

```
int len = list.getCount();
```

It gives me a right value.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Implement custom List Adapter.

```
public class YourAdapterName extends BaseAdapter{

private Context mContext;
private DataType mValuestoShow;//Use your DataType to pass values to adapter. 

/**
 * Constructor to be called to initialize adapter with values.
 * @param context
 * @param vector
 */
public YourAdapterName(Context context, DataType data){
    mContext = context;
    mValuestoShow = vector;
}

public int getCount() {
    if(null != mValuestoShow){
        return mValuestoShow.size();
    }
    return 0;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    if(position < mValuestoShow.size())
        return  mValuestoShow.get(position);
    else
        return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}



public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder ;
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater li =(LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txt_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_txt);
        holder.checkBox = (Checkbox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txt_name.setText(getItem(position).toString());
    holder.checkBox    // Do your task with checkbox.
    return convertView;
}

class ViewHolder {
    TextView txt_name;
    Checkbox checkBox;
}

}
```

your_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:padding = "10dp" >

<TextView
    android:id = "@+id/txt_type1"
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content" />

<CheckBox
    android:id = "@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I will see some solutions based on custom adapters to try to understand.

Comment: you should modify it as per your need.......I have posted a general custom list adapter.....

Comment: can you please see my question?

Comment: Can you please see that @Vineet ? <br/> I hope you dont mind to respond to these questions, I will be very gratefull.... <br/> (1) After that should I use list.setAdapter(YourAdapterName), something like that? <br/> (2) Why do you place Vector when is never used? <br/> (3) the function isEnabled what's the purpose? Thank you

Comment: give me some time I will post the code as per your requirement after testing.....

Comment: I have edited the code for checkbox. you can refer this tutorial over listview:http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Thank you very much. However I found the problem. Looks like there is a bug with setAdapter that's why setListAdapter is more "common". And so I changed my XML his is in the documentation, ListView should be placed in XML as <br/>
 
<listview android:id="@android:id/list" xmlns:android="#unknown"></listview>

and setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, aux)); and everything is owrking fine now. Many thanks for your help, very good tutorial by the way.